# Montar lista com arquivos em pastas diferente em android

Tags: android

Alguém pode me dar uma idéia de como montar uma lista, como itens que estão dentro de pastar separadas?
Exemplo:

pasta1: arquivos1 e arquivos2 
pasta2: arquivos3 e arquivos4

a lista ficaria:
arquivos1 
arquivos2 
arquivos3 
arquivos4

---

A lista que tenho é da seguinte forma:

```
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);
    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

            // Adding each song to SongList
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}
```

porém essa lista le apenas de uma pasta, ressaltando que preciso da função song.put, que utilizo...

Comment: Você consegue listar as pastas de um determinado diretório? Se souber, basta listar e adicionar tudo na mesma lista.

Comment: sim eu tenho a lista do diretório sdcard/pasta, o que preciso é que eu consiga adicionar em uma só lista, arquivos dentro de sdcard/pasta/pasta1,sdcard/pasta/pasta2,sdcard/pasta/pasta3, e assim por diante...

Answer (score 1):

Como está filtrando por extensão você perde os diretórios na listagem. Para isso, recomendo listar tudo e usar uma instância do Filtro para filtrar "manualmente" os arquivos que deseja, assim mantendo os diretórios durante a iteração.

Com essa adaptação o código fica:

```
public List<Map<String, String>> listarArquivos(File diretorio) {

    FileExtensionFilter filter = new FileExtensionFilter();
    File[] arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();
    List<Map<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    if (arquivos.length > 0) {
        for (File file : arquivos) {

            // Se o arquivo que esta iterando for um diretorio
            // É preciso chamar recursivamente essa função para
            // continuar recuperando os arquivos
            if(file.isDirectory()) {
                songsList.addAll(listarArquivos(file));
            } else if(filter.accept(file)) {
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();

                song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
                song.put("songPath", file.getPath());

                // Adding each song to SongList
                songsList.add(song);
            }
        }
    }

    // return songs list array
    return songsList;
}
```

Para chamar:

```
List<Map<String, String>> arquivos = listarArquivos(new File(MEDIA_PATH));
```

A chamada ao método `accept` vai variar dependendo de qual interface o Filtro está usando:

1. Se for um `FileFilter`, basta usar `filter.accept(file)`;
2. Se for um `FilenameFilter` basta usar `filter.accept(diretorio, file))`.

Uma recomendação off-topic: Crie um POJO para armazenar os dados de `songTitle` e `songPath`. Usar um `HashMap` para armazenar dois atributos é muito mais custoso que criar um objeto com dois atributos.